# Django ChoicesField divider?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a `ChoicesField` in my form, but I want to put a divider in it like this:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('CA', _('Canada')),
    ('US', _('United States')),
    (None, _('---')), # <----------
    ('AF', _('Afghanistan')),
    ('AX', _('Aland Islands')),
    ('AL', _('Albania')),
    ('DZ', _('Algeria')),
    ('AS', _('American Samoa')),
    # ...

class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, initial='CA')
```

What's the easiest way to make that unselectable, or at least give an error if the user picks it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a clean method to raise a validation error if any divider is selected.

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
  country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, initial='CA')

  def clean_country(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data["country"]
    if not data:
       raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a valid country.")
    return data
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices

You would format it like this:

```
COUNTRIES = [
    ("CA", _("Canada")),
    ("US", _("United States")),

    # This format will indent the nested tuples over and the 
    # "-----" will be un-selectable
    #
    ("---------------", ( # This will be a header for the items nested below
        ("AF", _("Afghanistan")),
        ('AX', _('Aland Islands')),
        ('AL', _('Albania')),
        ('DZ', _('Algeria')),
        ('AS', _('American Samoa')),


        )
    ),
]
```

Comment: I don't think I wanted the other ones indented, just separated.

Comment: I honestly would prefer that they weren't indented, but I haven't discovered a way to make a non-selectable header and not have it indented over. I just like that you don't have to write any validation logic for this method. Perhaps there is some kind of css rule that could be used to bump those over?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Django you are using, but I am on 1.10.1 and I used the following:

```
ICONS = (
    (None,                      ''),
    (None,                      '==Extra Contact Info=='),
    ('phone',                   'Phone'),
    ('phone',                   'Phone (square)'),
    ('fax',                     'Fax'),
    ('envelope',                'E-mail (black)'),
    ('envelope-o',              'E-mail (white/clear)'),
    (None,                      ''),
    (None,                      '==Social Media=='),
    ('facebook',                'Facebook'),
    ('facebook-official',       'Facebook (official)'),
    ('facebook-square',         'Facebook (square)'),
    ('google-plus',             'Google Plus'),
    ...
)
```

and that's all I used, and if a user selects any list item in a drop-down menu that has a 'None' value in it, it will bark at the user saying "This field is required."

Now... of course in my project, the choices list is being used in my whatever.com/admin page, but that may not be relevant.  What is relevant however, is that you have to ensure your model (or form) class field does not contain "blank = True".  By default it should be false if you omit it, in other words the field won't accept null or empty string values.  That should be all you need...